# Login functionality, click on button remember to forward the user to after login

Tags: javascript, php, html

Users should be logged in to be able to see the content. When someone presses a button where he is not allowed to go, a dropdown comes up where the user can login. Then the login screen is forwarded to the homepage of the website.

We want to remember in the login function which button the user pressed before the login screen, and forward the user to the right follow up content screen. Which simply said should be something like sending a variable with the login form and then making the login function refer to a variable page which gets chosen based on the variable send when someone pressed a certain button.

```
if ($rows == 1 AND variable = ???){
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; 
    $_SESSION['recordProfiel']=$recordProfiel;
    header("location: variablelink);
```

We use php.

Somehow I cant succeed in finding a working example online. Seems like something that more people do. So I think I am asking the wrong questions (stating the wrong google searches). What is the normal method to do this and can someone get me to a working example?

Comment: I don't think this is a .php problem. Just set up a click event handler for the initial button click and in the event handler, set some identifiable information about the button in `localStorage`.

Comment: Well you make that sound easy enough ... I am going to look into it

Comment: If each button calls a specific URL and then on the server you redirect them to the login page, then capturing $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] into a session variable (before you send them to the login page) will work. Once the login is approved then recall that from the session and do another redirect to that original URL

Comment: Since you are still inside of you webpage, you should still be able to get that using a bit of javascript and put this in an `<input type="hidden">`. Pass this onto your php.

Comment: Add one data attribute to the button which will store the destination url, and when button clicks on that store it in temporary cookie.

So once user is logged in and that special cookie is set then redirect the user. Please delete the cookie once user is redirected to the intended page.